# Compare and "Equalize" Collections

Tags: c#

Let's suppose we have a List collection A and an int array B. Now we need to see, independent of order, which elements from the array B are present in collection A. Add the elements that are missing and delete the elements that are not to be found int array B.

I have done this using the code below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < B.Length; k++)
    {
        if (A[i] == B[k]) goto Found;
    }

    A.RemoveAt(i);
    Found: continue;
}

for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < A.Count; k++)
    {
        if (A[k] == B[i]) goto Found;
    }

    A.Add(B[i]);
    Found: continue;
}
```

Is there a faster way to achieve the same result? Notice that I cannot just delete A and create a new one in accordance with B because this is just a simplified example.

Comment: Is `A` a `List<int>`?

Comment: Please add details why re-creating `A` is not an option. Depending on the reason, there might be more or less efficient approaches. Is it a data base? A web service?

Comment: So, to clarify: take A.  Remove all the elements from A that are not in B.  Afterwards, go through B, and if the element isn't already in A, add it to A.

How does this collection differ from B?

Comment: @MarkSowul: Order of elements. The point doesn't seem to be that there's much of a difference, though. Maybe the instance `A` is shared in different places of the program and re-assigning it would break other things. Do we really need the reason?

Comment: Given the code sample, yes, I would say we should be further clarifying the requirements.  Maybe they just need to be sorted.  Maybe the order _isn't_ important.  Maybe the ints are just an example and the issue is object identity.  Without knowing the requirements of `A` it isn't possible to suggest a speed-up.

Comment: @Mark: Quoting from the question: "Now we need to see, independent of order, which elements from the array B are present in collection A".

Comment: Hence, further clarification is warranted, because if order is independent, then there's something else we're missing if we can't just return `B`

Answer (score 1):

The very short (and fairly fast) version would be

```
A.Clear();
A.AddRange(B);
```

but perhaps you don't really want that either. You can shorten your code a bit when using the `Contains` method, though:

```
for (int i = A.Count; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!B.Contains(A[i])) {
    A.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
foreach (var item in B) {
  if (!A.Contains(item)) {
    A.Add(item);
  }
}
```

The first loop cannot be a `foreach` loop because `A` is modified while it is being iterated over. It also runs backwards to ensure that every item is looked at.

However, this has quadratic runtime (more precisely: *O*(|A| · |B|)) and can get slow rather quickly (pun not intended) with large lists. For better runtime (albeit higher memory requirements) you may need to use `HashSet`s for the `Contains` tests requiring only *O*(|A| + |B|) runtime performance at the cost of *O*(|A| + |B|) more memory.

This is a quite long-winded way of getting to the point, though: If you don't care about *order* of your items, then it seems like your lists are more like sets. In that case, a set data structure makes more sense because it can do those operations efficiently. And you apparently don't care about element order, because you're just adding missing items at the end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think using LINQ should be fast:

```
A.RemoveAll(tmp => !B.Contains(tmp));
A.AddRange(B.Where(tmp => !A.Contains(tmp)));
```

EDIT: as pointed out by Joey this is still only O(|A| · |B|).

Comment: »optimized« is such a strong word. This still has complexity *O* (|A| · |B|), the same as their original code.

Comment: @Joey sorry, used the wrong word. I indeed just shortened the code of my previous version.

Answer (score 1):

It's futile, in the end you will get collection B all over again. just create collection A based on array B. simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

OK I will give you some more details. The example I set above was oversimplified. What I actually have is an XML file which is loaded on an XElement. There are child nodes with specific attributes mapping precisely to the properties of a custom type in my application. Every child node creates an instance of the aforementioned type.

For purposes of extensibility, if I need to add a new property to the custom type, I want all records in the XML file to be updated with the new attribute with an empty value. And if I delete a property, I want the opposite. So here, I must check the collection of Attributes towards the PropertyInfo[] of the custom type. I cannot delete all of the Attributes and recreate them again because their values will be lost as well.

In my approach, I could see that some checks were done twice and because I am really novice, I thought that maybe this was a casual issue that is dealt with a way I could not think of. Thank you all for the nice replys.